# Angular router navigate works only after second submitting

Tags: angular

I'm trying to redirect user after logging in. What's the matter - I've got logging page without `returnUrl` parameter - `http://localhost:4200/login`. I fill logging form, and submit it for the first time. It shows me email of the user in the navbar (so it confirms that I'm logged in) but nothing happens when it comes to redirecting - instead the `returnUrl` appears in url - `http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2F`. Only after submitting it for the second time it redirects to the homepage.
In the case when there is `returnUrl` parameter - `http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=%2Fcheck-out`, after first submitting the url stays the same, and only after submitting it for the second time it redirects to checkout page.
I think it is `AuthGuard` which causes the problem, it may be called before logging in, that's why it blocks visiting subpages and redirects me to login page with these subpages as return parameter. But how can I fix it?

```
LoginComponent

ngOnInit() {
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '';
    }

  tryLogin(values) {
      this.authService.loginUser(values)
        .then(res => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
        }, err => {
            this.loginWarn = err;
            this.loginInfo = '';
        });
  }
```

---

```
AuthService

 public loginUser(values) {
      return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password);
  }
```

---

```
Routes
const appRoutes: Routes = [
...
    { path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
...];
```

---

```
AuthGuard
...
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if(!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

---

```
AuthService
   userData: any;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
          if (user) {
              this.userData = user;
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
          } else {
              localStorage.setItem('user', null);
          }
      });
  }
get isLoggedIn() {
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      return user !== null;
  }
```

Comment: U guess it does not work because your user is not set in the localStorage during the first click.

Comment: @Stefan it does, that's why I mentioned that it shows me user's email in a navbar after first click.

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere?